# Placement of icon with text issue in fluid layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

[image]

Am trying to make things look like the above image, this is for the fluid layout, but no matter what i do, that phone icon with the number 1-844.....does not move to right next to talk to us. Here is JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtf205mk/

```
.fluid {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.top_nav_icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.call_icon_header {
  content: url(images/call-us-icon.png);
  float: left;
}
.talk_icon_header {
  content: url(images/talk-to-us-icon.png);
  float: left;
}
.float_right {
  float: right;
}
.top_nav_icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.top_nav_list1 {
  float: left;
}
.top_nav_list1_1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
.top_nav_list1_2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  clear: none;
}
.top_nav_list1_2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  clear: none;
}
```

Am using DW CC, but the visual aids is nowhere helping me in moving things to the right.

Can anyone help with this one please, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used pseudo elements to achieve your functionality requirements:

The main point to note that I want you to take from here is my use of `display:inline-block;`

```css
.phone,
.talk {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 10px; /*this is to 'vertically align' the text (adjust for your image height)*/
}
.phone:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300); /*change to phone icon*/
}
.talk:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300); /*change to chat icon*/
}
```

```html
<div class="phone">phone here</div>
<div class="talk">chat here</div>
```

---

As a side note, I would like to point out my personal *hate* for floating elements, as this *really* can mess things up in terms of positioning elements.

This is why we have `display` and `positioning` css rules for.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this one, but could i know if this works for a fluid layout? rwd website i mean?

Comment: once the width is ~150px, the chat would wrap (I think I placed the chat to the right in my example)

Comment: Yes, that is fine, i have placed it now, it is working fine, checking for mobile and tab version.